# Client Disconnecting on client.emit - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I'vee been working on this for days and have made the problem as simple as i can make it.

I just have a button that sends a command to my node.js server which just console.logs the phrase 'testing' and also emits a signal to the client to run a function.

The problem is the client is disconnecting?! However, it dows not disconnect on the second try.

Client:

```
<button onclick="test()">Login</button>

var socket  = io.connect('http://54.213.92.113:8080');

function test(){
                    socket.emit('test');
                    }

socket.on('conf', function () {
                    alert("testing worked");
                    }
```

server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {

        client.on('test', function(){
        client.emit('conf);
        console.log("testing");
        });
});
```

Here is my log. Again, the code appears to work on the second try:

1st try:

```
info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"conf"}
testing
   info  - transport end (socket end)
   debug - set close timeout for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - cleared close timeout for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
```

after 2nd try:

```
 info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"conf"}
testing
   info  - transport end (socket end)
   debug - set close timeout for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - cleared close timeout for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Egh72p-hOLFSpLh2CS7m
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client PCzh1CS-tze49XHaCS7n
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"conf"}
testing
```

I've been researching this for a while and have gotten absolutely nowhere. Does anyone know why this code isn't working on the first try? - The alert only comes up after the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: [socket.io client connection cannot be made on the 2nd time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933124/socket-io-client-connection-cannot-be-made-on-the-2nd-time)

```
// in client
io.connect('host:port', { 'force new connection': true });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI, you can write code verbatim by indenting it four spaces or by putting it inside of backticks.